# BTRFS & F2FS userspace utilites cross compilation

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded-linux, btrfs

Is there any weblink/document which describes the steps to cross-compile btrfs & F2fs user space utilities ?
Any steps ?
special tuning suggestion for arm based board.(AM335x) ?

Comment: There is already some effort for cross compilation for btrfs prog happening [refer](https://gitorious.org/baserock-morphs/btrfs-progs/commit/3516e6b56e5026d6716e9fd1e3f70ded0f147e6c). I am not sure about the specific board, basically these are already being build for arch imo.

Comment: @askb :Thank you for kind attention, I think that patch is pretty old, i do have make file where CC is defined. because of different dependency i am not able to build it. First i was getting error related to uuid.h not found and once i resolved that now i am stuck at ext2_fs.h file not found error..so if some has already done it they tell what all the dependency i should build before building btrfs